# SQL query to find False Negatives w.r.t Data Matching or Entity Resolution

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity, resolution, matching

Suppose I have two different ID's assigned for same record. For example

```
RecordID | ID1 | ID2
--------------------
1        | X   | A
2        | X   | B
3        | Y   | C
4        | Y   | C
5        | Y   | D
6        | Z   | E
7        | Z   | E
```

Now, I want to get the records where `ID1` is assigned to the same value where as `ID2` is assigned to a different value.

For example, I want to get:

```
1, X, A
2, X, B
```

Here ID1 assigned it X where as ID2 assigned it A and B, two different values.

Is it possible to write a query in SQL or SQL server that will return such records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery where, for each row, you poke through the table and see if any other rows match a certain criteria related to it.

pseudo sql:

```
select 
      t1.id, 
      t1.variable, 
      t1.value 
   from 
      table t1 
   where 
      exists ( select 1 
                  from t2 
                  where t2.id != t1.id 
                    and t2.variable == t1.variable 
                    and t2.value != t1.value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your Query worked for me. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirements, I think all you need is an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.*
FROM YourTable T
  JOIN YourTable T2 ON T.ID1 = T2.ID1 AND T.ID2 <> T2.ID2
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23b82/2).

Please note, in this example it returns all rows from X and Y.  X because of A and B; Y because of C and D.  Is this correct?

Good luck.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wil test your query tomorrow and tell you if it worked.

Comment: Thanks. However, the SQL query is returning all the rows in the table

Comment: @Huzaifa -- can you elaborate?  Was my SQL Fiddle incorrect for you?  Rows with Z aren't returned, where rows with X and Y are because they have different ID2 values associated with them.

Comment: Its returning all the rows in the database. I have around 4000 records. Its returning me all of them. where exists query worked for me though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT RecordID, ID1, ID2
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT ID1
              FROM yourtable
              GROUP BY ID1
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID2)>1);
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e02fa/1).

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH minmax AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    minID2 = MIN(ID2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID1),
    maxID2 = MAX(ID2) OVER (PARTITION BY ID1)
  FROM atable
)
SELECT
  RecordID,
  ID1,
  ID2
FROM minmax
WHERE minID2 <> maxID2
;
```

In the `minmax` CTE, two more columns are added which hold minimum and maximum `ID2` for every group of rows with the same `ID1`. The main query returns only those rows where the corresponding minimum `ID2` doesn't match the maximum `ID2`.

Comment: Its returning me all the rows in the table.